# What are the most profitable tailoring recipes?

Tags: rimworld, rimworld-royalty

There are many different tailoring recipes available to craft for your pawns once you research Complex Clothing (and even more with the Noble Clothing and Royal Clothing options!), each requiring a differing amount of both labor and materials.

While both quality and material can affect the final value of the item, they're moot comparatively, assuming the quantity & time remain the same. (Do any clothing materials have work time adjustments? I know building furniture out of stone is slower than metal or wood)

There are two equally interesting maximums I'd like to consider (though they may be the same) --

- The tailoring recipe that maximizes profit / time
- The tailoring recipe that maximizes profit / material

What should I be making in order to most-quickly grow my burgeoning clothing franchise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After Roybin93's answer pointed me at the Wiki, I went in and [added the new items](https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Electric_tailoring_bench) to the table.

While Tribalwear's "Value / Work" remains uncontested, "Value / Material" and "Value / Weight" both have been usurped by the new recipes.

**All six*** of the new recipes beat out the duster in terms of Value, and if you're committed to bringing your goods to the traders (instead of waiting for them to come to you), the Value / Weight and Value / Material of the new Hat items will likely out-perform any previous Tuque-based industry.

In summary:

- If the limiting factor is Pawn time, make **Tribalwear**
- If the limiting factor is Textile materials, make **Corsets** or **Dusters** (depending on whether you've unlocked Noble Apparel)
- If the limiting factor is caravan carry weight, make **Top Hats**.

*Top Hats and Lady's Hats are identical in terms of cost, material, and value. The same holds true for Royal Vests and Corsets. The only difference between these pairs is which gender pawns they cause mood debuffs for when worn (due to wearing clothing *clearly* made for the other gender)

Comment: I'm confused by the wording.  You say that all other recipes "beat out the duster", but you then say that the duster is the best.  Do you mean the reverse; that "the duster beats out the others" instead?

Comment: @SouthpawHare Duster is only the best if you don't have the technology for Noble / Royal Attire.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately there are already two useful tables containing the answer to this very question. But unfortunately the DLCs clothing and materials are not yet included in this list, thus this answer is incomplete.

> The first table contains the type of item you should tailor to get the most profit. ->[Tailoring goods](https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Electric_tailoring_bench)
>
> The second table shows you the value of each textile to determine which one is the best to tailor.-> [Textiles](https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Textiles)

As you can see from the first table, value/work(profit/time) is the highest in tribal-wear but value/materials(profit/material) is highest in dusters.

To calculate, how much money you will get for your clothing just multiply the "Base Market Value" from the first table with the "Market Value" from the textile table. Don't forget to factor in the [Qualitys](https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Quality) market value as well.

Comment: Another worthwhile measure would be value/weight, to indicate which type of clothing is most worthwhile to carry in a caravan.